# Magento 1.14.1.0 and recommended nginx version

Tags: nginx, ee-1.14

Magento mentions [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html) that the system requirements for nginx is version 1.7.x. But I'm wondering what is the recommended version? Is there a reason I should just update to 1.7 and not go to 1.8, 1.9, or 1.10? Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Nginx versions newer than 1.7 only add new features and bux fixes. An nginx configuration based on 1.7 should still work fine on 1.10.

I have used both 1.8 and 1.9 on production Magento environments with no problems whatsoever. Now that 1.10 is out as the latest stable version I would probably go for that.

Comment: Okay, cool. I'm currently on 1.6. Will I need to reconfigure anything if I update?

Comment: I can't say for sure as it would depend on the modules enabled in the different nginx installs. If you are just using it as a basic webserver though, then I would say you will more than likely be fine. I have used the same config in different versions of nginx quite a bit and never had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 1 and 2 works perfect with any latest mainline or stable Nginx versions**  `tested`

you must always use the latest version.
http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html
latest nginx version has lots of improvements, many new features, networking, cpu, memory and other: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-10-1-11-released/

http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.10

Configure arguments common for nginx binaries from pre-built packages:

```
--prefix=/etc/nginx
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp
--user=nginx
--group=nginx
--with-http_ssl_module
--with-http_realip_module
--with-http_addition_module
--with-http_sub_module
--with-http_dav_module
--with-http_flv_module
--with-http_mp4_module
--with-http_gunzip_module
--with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_random_index_module
--with-http_secure_link_module
--with-http_stub_status_module
--with-http_auth_request_module
--with-threads
--with-stream
--with-stream_ssl_module
--with-http_slice_module
--with-mail
--with-mail_ssl_module
--with-file-aio
--with-http_v2_module
--with-ipv6
```

Main nginx package is built with all modules that do not require additional libraries to avoid extra dependencies.

Dynamic Modules

Since version 1.9.11, nginx supports dynamic modules. Currently, the following modules are built as dynamic and shipped as separate packages:

```
nginx-module-geoip
nginx-module-image-filter
nginx-module-njs
nginx-module-perl
nginx-module-xslt
```